# Product of cyclic matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

So I've come across the following problem:

Lets say we have two Matrices, $A,B \in \operatorname{GL}_n(K)$ which are cyclic. By that I mean that their rows are cyclic shifts of a vector,

$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 &...& a_n\\
a_n & a_1 & a_2 &...& a_{n-1}\\
& & \vdots\\
\end{pmatrix}
\\
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 &...& b_n\\
b_n & b_1 & b_2 &...& b_{n-1}\\
& & \vdots\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
And also, the matrice's non-zero entries are disjunct.

I've computed a few examples and they all lead me to believe that their product again is cyclic matrix, however I cant think of an easy argument as to why that should be the case.

Does anyone have an Idea, as to what would be an easy argument for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $ij$ entry of $AB$ is the $i$th row of $A$ times the $j$th column of $B$.  This is equal to the $1$st row of $A$ times the $(j-i)$th column of $B$ (computed $\bmod{n}$; this is because of the cyclic shift).  Call this $c_{j-i}$.  Then you can see that
$$AB = \begin{pmatrix} c_{0} & c_{1} & \ldots & c_{n-1}\\ c_{n-1} & c_{0} & \ldots & c_{n-2}\\ \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\ c_{1} & c_{2} & \ldots & c_{0} \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already solved this once before, but couldn't see why this should be the case for the hell of it anymore.